# Rewrite AST switch stmt with new caseClause

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to add new caseClause into switch statement by Golang AST but keep getting failure. Could you please help check how to change below snippet for below case statement:

```
case "all":
        def = pool.All{}



 func handleSwitch(ss *ast.SwitchStmt) (ast.Node, bool) {   
        expr := make([]ast.Expr, 1)
        body := make([]ast.Stmt, 1)
        bl := &ast.BasicLit{Kind: token.STRING, Value: "\"all\""}
        expr = append(expr, bl)
        lhs := make([]ast.Expr, 1)
        ident := &ast.Ident{Name: "def"}
        lhs = append(lhs, ident)
        xIdent := &ast.Ident{Name: "pool"}
        sIdent := &ast.Ident{Name: "All"}
        rhs := make([]ast.Expr, 1)
        cl := &ast.CompositeLit {
            Type: &ast.SelectorExpr{
                X: xIdent,
                Sel: sIdent,
            },
        }
        rhs = append(rhs, cl)
        as := &ast.AssignStmt{
            Lhs: lhs,
            Tok: token.ASSIGN,
            Rhs: rhs,
        }
        body = append(body, as)
        cc := &ast.CaseClause{
            List: expr,
            Body: body,
        }
        newCases = append(newCases, cc)
        ss.Body = &ast.BlockStmt{
            List: newCases,
        }
        return ss, true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're allocating slices with `make(T, N)` and then you're using `append` with the assumption that it appends from the 0th position. However, in actuality, `append` will add a new element to the end of a slice and any of its preceding elements will remain unchanged, which is this case means `nil`, and that `nil` is what breaks the AST.

See the problem in code:

```golang
expr := make([]ast.Expr, 1)
fmt.Println(expr)
// [<nil>]

bl := &ast.BasicLit{ ... }

expr = append(expr, bl)
fmt.Println(expr)
// [<nil> 0xc0000a6020]
```

To fix this you can either do:

```golang
expr := make([]ast.Expr, 0) // or []ast.Expr{}
fmt.Println(expr)
// []

expr = append(expr, bl)
fmt.Println(expr)
// [0xc00000c0c0]
```

or:

```golang
expr := make([]ast.Expr, 1)
fmt.Println(expr)
// [<nil>]

expr[0] = bl
fmt.Println(expr)
// [0xc000114020]
```

https://play.golang.org/p/g78hrrv2VDD